# Is paging possible in kendo-ui pivot grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get paging in Telerik's kendo-ui pivot grid control.
Is this possible? I did some research to find about this. I found this http://www.telerik.com/forums/paging-in-pivotgrid, which says The PivotDataSource component does not support paging. There's another link which shows paging in Telerik's ASP.NET Pivot Table which is called RadPivotGrid. I got little confused, whether paging is available in Kendo-UI pivot grid control. Any thoughts? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik's kendo-ui pivot grid is a front-end solution. It does not have paging.

RadPivotGrid is a back-end solution and it has paging.

Actually, RadPivotGrid needs paging because only part of the grid that should be displayed is sent to the browser. In this case there is not enough data in the browser to allow users to use smooth and natural live scrolling. They provide paging instead. I, personally, consider paging as a limitation, when a component cannot afford to have live scrolling.

Telerik's kendo-ui pivot grid holds multidimensional query response in browser's memory. Hence, there is no need for paging. You can simply scroll vertically and horizontally to access the data you need. As it is written on Telerik's website http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid in features description:
"**Scrolling**
Telerik Kendo UI Pivot Grid lets your end-users manipulate huge amounts of data. In case this data cannot fit on one page, the widget also supports scrolling and frozen header rows."